# skew normal distribution

Tags: statistics

we have skew normal distribution with location=0, scale =1 and shape =0 then it is same as standard normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.but if we change the shape parameter say shape=5 then mean and variance also changes.how can we fix mean and variance with different values of shape parameter

Comment: I think you'd get a better response on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might ask this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/. But if you do, please add more detail and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look after how the mean and variance of a skew normal distribution can be computed and you got the answer! Knowing that the mean looks like:

[image]    and     [image]

You can see, that with a xi=0 (location), omega=1 (scale) and alpha=0 (shape) you really get a standard normal distribution (with mean=0, standard deviation=1):

[image]

If you only change the alpha (shape) to 5, you can except the mean will differ a lot, and will be positive. If you want to hold the mean around zero with a higher alpha (shape), you will have to decrease other parameters, e.g.: the omega (scale). The most obvious solution could be to set it to zero instead of 1. See:
[image]

Mean is set, we have to get a variance equal to zero with a omega set to zero and shape set to 5. The formula is known:

[image]

With our known parameters:

[image]

Which is insane :) That cannot be done this way. You may also go back and alter the value of xi instead of omega to get a mean equal to zero. But that way you might first compute the only possible value of omega with the formula of variance given.

[image]

Then the omega should be around 1.605681 (negative or positive).

Getting back to mean:

[image]

So, with the following parameters you should get a distribution you was intended to:

> location = 1.256269 (negative or positive), scale = 1.605681 (negative or positive) and shape = 5.

**Please, someone test it, as I might miscalculated somewhere with the given example.**

Comment: Ok, I could not help doing the tests also in R (with `sn` package), and looks like everything is just fine with the given parameters (location and scale should have opposite sign): mean=0, var=1 and looks skew (with a skewness around 0.8619845)!

Comment: i did not understand the meaning of your last statement about test in R.can u elaborate it one more time?thanks

Comment: if we have 3 equation of mean,variance and skewness then how can we fix location, scale and shape parameter.can u explain about it?

Comment: @Amber: I did some tests to see if my computation was right, you have nothing to do with it. But about your other comment: you really should read about the subject, as I think there is no sense in speaking about a subject you are not familiar with. You might start with wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution or with any basic statistics book.

Comment: how did u calculate the skew parameter(with a skewness around 0.8619845)?because i am not getting the same as u got?i understand the article but i m not figuring out it?

Comment: @Amber: It was calculated on the test data, that is why I wrote "around". Computing by the formula (see on e.g. Wikipedia linked above), you should get a skewness ~0.850965. Another issu: as I think I gave a correct answer, are you willing to accept it, or do you see any problem with it?

Comment: if i calculate the location ,scale and shape parameter in terms of mean ,variance and skewness then how can i get the skew normal distributed random numbers.

Comment: @Amber: Wikipedia has some idea about the theory of generating random numbers based on spec. distributions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Generation_from_a_probability_distribution), but I am sure Matlab would have a function making this exercise a lot simpler. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Matlab, though I could help you in R.

Comment: actually in R if we use 'sn' package then we can generate the multivariate skew normal random variables but i am not much familiar with R.i have opened the installed this package but unfortunately i am not getting hoe to use 'rsn' and "mrsn" function, these are the functions for uni variate and multivariate skew normal distribution.when i type it on the command window it says me that i don't have these function so how to work with these?

Comment: `rsn(n=100, location=1.256269, scale=1.605681, shape=5)` will generate 100 random values from the desired distribution. Please open new questions for other topics in the future.