# How to plot a distribution based on moments

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics, probability-density

I am wondering how, in Matlab, to plot a continuous pdf with the following information?

```
mean=-0.3731
standard deviation= 5.6190
skewness=-3.0003
kurtosis=13.1722
```

or alternative how do I plot a continous pdf that is not normal? (like it is skewness and has kurtosis, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those parameters don't define a distribution, but normally you would use "makedist" in matlab to generate a probability distribution object and then plot it.

The following thread has some discussion on defining a distribution. [How to generate distributions given, mean, SD, skew and kurtosis in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807398/how-to-generate-distributions-given-mean-sd-skew-and-kurtosis-in-r)

Based on your comment below, I think you are looking for something like the following functio that generates a m by n matrix of random values with the following parameters:

```
r = pearsrnd(mu,sigma,skew,kurt,m,n)
```

Comment: But if I would like to start with a normal distribution with the mean and standard deviation, then transform it to fit the skewness and kurtosis, is that doable?

Comment: @user1664484 I think there are infinitely many solutions for that. A finite number of moments don't determine the distribution

Comment: @user1664484 I updated my answer with what seems to be what you are looking for.