# Altering distribution of one dataset to match another dataset

Tags: r, statistics

I have 2 datasets, one of modeled (artificial) data and another with observed data. They have slightly different statistical distributions and I want to force the modeled data to match the observed data distribution in the spread of the data. In other words, I need the modeled data to better represent the tails of the observed data. Here's an example.

```
model <- c(37.50,46.79,48.30,46.04,43.40,39.25,38.49,49.51,40.38,36.98,40.00,
38.49,37.74,47.92,44.53,44.91,44.91,40.00,41.51,47.92,36.98,43.40,
42.26,41.89,38.87,43.02,39.25,40.38,42.64,36.98,44.15,44.91,43.40,
49.81,38.87,40.00,52.45,53.13,47.92,52.45,44.91,29.54,27.13,35.60,
45.34,43.37,54.15,42.77,42.88,44.26,27.14,39.31,24.80,16.62,30.30,
36.39,28.60,28.53,35.84,31.10,34.55,52.65,48.81,43.42,52.49,38.00,
38.65,34.54,37.70,38.11,43.05,29.95,32.48,24.63,35.33,41.34)

observed <- c(39.50,44.79,58.28,56.04,53.40,59.25,48.49,54.51,35.38,39.98,28.00,
28.49,27.74,51.92,42.53,44.91,44.91,40.00,41.51,47.92,36.98,53.40,
42.26,42.89,43.87,43.02,39.25,40.38,42.64,36.98,44.15,44.91,43.40,
52.81,36.87,47.00,52.45,53.13,47.92,52.45,44.91,29.54,27.13,35.60,
51.34,43.37,51.15,42.77,42.88,44.26,27.14,39.31,24.80,12.62,30.30,
34.39,25.60,38.53,35.84,31.10,34.55,52.65,48.81,43.42,52.49,38.00,
34.65,39.54,47.70,38.11,43.05,29.95,22.48,24.63,35.33,41.34)

summary(model)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
16.62   36.98   40.38   40.28   44.91   54.15 

summary(observed)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
12.62   35.54   42.58   41.10   47.76   59.2
```

How can I force the model data to have the variability that the observed has in R?

Comment: This seems more like a mathematical discussion then a programming one. Perhaps it would do well on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)? (Also, "higher frequency" has no context with the current data. You may need to alter your sample to correctly reflect the time-series nature.)

Comment: Additionally, you should include the distribution type and parameters of the `model` distribution, unless it is just another empirical distribution, in which case you need to be clear that you have two empirical distributions.

Comment: @r2evans good point, I got rid of the extra question. I'm unsure of what the distribution type and parameters are for the `model` distribution, but it is modeled data

Comment: If it is modeled data, there is nothing that can be done to adjust the variance without discarding the fact that it is a "real model". That is, if you treat it as empirical data and try [distribution fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_fitting), then you'll be creating a new "model" with whatever variance modification you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just modeling the distribution of `observed`? If so, you could generate a kernel density estimate from the observations and then resample from that modeled density distribution. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

First we generate a density estimate from the observed values. This is our model of the distribution of the observed values. `adjust` is a parameter that determines the bandwidth. The default value is 1. Smaller values result in less smoothing (i.e., a density estimate that more closely follows small-scale structure in the data):

```
dens.obs = density(observed, adjust=0.8)
```

Now, resample from the density estimate to get the modeled values. We set `prob=dens.obs$y` so that the probability of a value in `dens.obs$x` being chosen is proportional to its modeled density.

```
set.seed(439)
resample.obs = sample(dens.obs$x, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=dens.obs$y)
```

Put observed and modeled values in a data frame in preparation for plotting:

```
dat = data.frame(value=c(observed,resample.obs), 
                 group=rep(c("Observed","Modeled"), c(length(observed),length(resample.obs))))
```

The ECDF (empirical cumulative distribution function) plot below shows that sampling from the kernel density estimate gives samples with a distribution similar to the observed data:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(value, fill=group, colour=group)) +
  stat_ecdf(geom="step") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also plot the density distribution of the observed data and the values sampled from the modeled distribution (using the same value for the `adjust` parameter as we used above).

```
ggplot(dat, aes(value, fill=group, colour=group)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.4, adjust=0.8) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer [How to generate distributions given, mean, SD, skew and kurtosis in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807398/how-to-generate-distributions-given-mean-sd-skew-and-kurtosis-in-r).

It discusses use of the `SuppDists` package. This package permits you to create a distribution by creating a set of parameters based on the [Johnson system of distributions](http://www.marine.usf.edu/user/djones/jctm/jctm.html).