# Match dataset distribution to another

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, probability, distribution

I have 2 observed datasets, and I wish to match their distributions according to 2 features.

In elaboration - I want to keep one dataset as is, and filter the other according to 2 features's distributions in the first.

I searched and found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152038/altering-distribution-of-one-dataset-to-match-another-dataset) for R language:

Anyone knows how to do the same thing in python?
Thanks!